# make a filter in blazor im working with but when it works the renderizing number of page not works good

Tags: blazor

some one can help me with that I'm trying this:

```
    private string searchTerm = "";
        private string SearchTerm
        {
            get { return searchTerm; }
            set { searchTerm = value; FilterRecords(); }
        }
```

i am doing this but the records when seratfilter is not empty the pagination note refresh at all only show 36 of 40 pagezie when filtering is n the number of pagination is so many when filtering is too n not refreshing what i am missing or what it needs to refresh my list objerct; n  my pagination footer, i dontk know, some one to help me,

```
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        { if (searchTerm == "" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
            {
             //here iget my data to list
            proof();
            }
            else { }

        //display total page buttons
        pagerSize = 3;
        pageSize = 40;
        curPage = 1;

        articleModel = await ListAll((curPage - 1) * pageSize, pageSize, sortColumnName, 
        sortDir, searchTerm);
        totalRecords = await Count(searchTerm);
       
        totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalRecords / (decimal)pageSize);
        SetPagerSize("forward");
     
    }

    public void FilterRecords()
        {
            endPage = 0;
            this.OnInitializedAsync().Wait();
        }
```

My Methosto retrive data

```
    public Task<int> Count(string search)
        {
            var totArticle = outputFileList.Where(x => x.name.Contains(search)).Count();
            return Task.FromResult(totArticle);
        }

     public  Task<List<FileList>> ListAll(int skip, int take, string orderBy, string 
     direction = "DESC", string search = "")
        {
            var articles = outputFileList.Skip(skip).Take(take).Where(x => 
     x.name.Contains(search)).ToList();
            return Task.FromResult(articles);
        }
```

```
but the first time the result is good all as i wanted but when i do the filter doesnt works check the results
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh0GM.png)

and it show 40 per page
but when filtering is shows 36 in one 29 ente next n so on it only filtering by pages n not rendering all the list n restart the pagination not works  at all
what can i do some suggestions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDLI5.png)

Comment: You are filtering your skip and take result. I think you should reorder the clauses... Where -> Skip -> Take

Comment: ok bro let me try this   public  Task<List<FileList>> ListAll(int skip, int take, string search = "")
    {

        var articles = outputFileList.Where(x => x.name.Contains(search)).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();

        return Task.FromResult(articles);
    }

Comment: tahnk u it works thank u bro godbless u

Comment: yh i forget the ordeer where, skip, take thanks